# What do I need to do to connect to public wifi in a local shop?

Tags: wireless

I go into a local coffee shop with public wifi and try to connect.  The connection shows up in network manager so I click on it and it says it is connected.  Apparently the next thing I should do is open a browser and accept the acceptable use policy.  However when I open Firefox it just shows the start page which I'm assuming is local and if I try to go anyplace on the internet says "connecting" and never goes anyplace.  How am I supposed to get to the "Acceptable Use" page?

The network manager is set to Automatic for everthing and when I sit down and click connect on the indicator icon, after it says connected, it appears to be ready to go.  If I edit things in the connection properties that I know will cause it to fail the browser shows the "server not found" page when I try to access the internet, but if I leave everthing set to automatic and get the connection shown below it just freezes at "connecting".

I have tried firefox and chromium and they both act the same, but could there be something in the way I have my browsers configured that aren't allowing them to re-direct to the "acceptable use" page?  Are there other tools that might help diagnose what is going on?

```
State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [TimHortons-US-Staging] ---------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwl3945
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *TimHortons-US-Staging: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 67

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.2.242.244
    Prefix:          16 (255.255.0.0)
    Gateway:         10.2.1.1

    DNS:             208.67.222.222
    DNS:             208.67.220.220
```

Comment: Ensure that your IP, gateway, and DNS are set to "dynamic" to allow the wifi router to assign them.

Comment: It should work "as it". I do it all the time and never encountered problems, so I'm going with @DigitalChris on this.

Comment: I am also encountering this problem and have not found a solution yet. I can connect from my phone (Android) or Windows, but not Ubuntu. Also, I have everything set to dynamic as @DigitalChris suggested didn't make a difference.

Comment: For me, I can get this to work by using Chromium instead of Firefox.

Comment: I think I have the same issues, in two different libraries I frequent. Unfortunately, sometime it works, after I try for five-ten minutes. Sometimes it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and found that I could make a curl request just fine:

```
$ curl -vL "https://www.google.com"
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.19.196...
```

When I connected directly to that IP in chrome(ium), I got shown the guard page, and could tick the necessary box. YMMV.